# Automatic Windows Authentication on public domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm developing a Asp.NET Core web application, and I enabled Windows Authentication on it by following the official Microsoft guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Authentication works, but there's one thing that I'm not clear on. If I access the website with a browser from a machine that is in the Windows Domain, I have two different behaviors depending on how I access it:

- If I access using the machine name in the address (example: https://devmachine01/ ) the browser logs in automatically and I'm authenticated, without any action required on the user's part
- If I access using the machine's public domain name (example: https://mypublicwebsite.com) the browser asks me to enter my windows credentials, like in the image below:
  [image]

My questions at this point are:

1. is there a way to make the browser log in automatically even if I
   access with the public domain instead of the machine name?
   (obviously I only expect this to work automatically if the machine
   where the browser is running is logged in to the domain)
2. if the
   answer to the first question is no, can I at least configure my
   Asp.NET Core web application so that it remembers the user, so the
   user only has to log in once (with a cookie or similar mechanism)?
   With the instructions provided in the article I linked above the
   user has to re-enter his credentials every time he closes and
   reopens the browser, which is not the most convenient.

Comment: Normally the server has to believe its part of a local/trusted

Comment: @BugFinder: sorry, but can you expand a bit on that? Forgive me but I'm new to this method of authentication and I'm not really sure what you're talking about... are you saying this depends on how the server is configured? Do you mean the machine or my web app?

Comment: Its browser settings not anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Authentication, the authentication scheme which allows automatic login, is predicated on everything belonging to the same domain: the identity provider (AD), the web server, and the client (local machine). A public website, by very definition, is not part of the domain, and thus Windows Auth (or at least the automatic login functionality thereof) cannot function in such an environment.

You can still technically use Windows Auth or AD in general. Azure Active Directory, for example, is designed to work in distributed environments. However, you must manually authenticate (either via traditional username and password or via an OAuth flow). You cannot have automatic login with a public website.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't read you question closely enough initially. While it doesn't change my answer, it does bear a bit more explanation. While the machine is technically on the domain, it's outward facing facade is *not*. This is why accessing it via hostname works, but via a actual web domain does not. That said, you're absolute *insane* for exposing a computer on your domain to the internet at large. Even if you *could* get this to work, the security risk of the hole you're opening far outsizes a simple nicety such as automatic login. Your internal network should be *internal*, and you should remove this machine from the domain *immediately*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very informative. The machine is not yet exposed, we're still evaluating the best solution for this. After your warning, I think we'll probably opt for a solution where only machines in the internal network (physically or virtually via VPN) have access to the server.